# How to use touch handlers? (does GWT support them?)

Tags: gwt

I have a MouseDownHandler, MouseMoveHandler, and MouseUpHandler attached to a panel. I'd like to get the corresponding touch events to work the same way too. Is there any example of how this works with GWT?

The events and handlers section in the docs are quite sparse:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiHandlers

so I must be missing it somewhere,

Thanks

----- Update ------------

Ok so added this, but it doesn't fire:

```
// touchTest is just a div with width/height = 100%
RootPanel rp = RootPanel.get("touchTest"); 
rp.sinkEvents(Event.TOUCHEVENTS);
rp.addHandler(new TouchStartHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onTouchStart(TouchStartEvent event) {
         // touch down!
    }
}, TouchStartEvent.getType());
```

I have a mousedownhandler attached to the div like above, and it works fine when run in a desktop browser. Is there soething else we need to do?

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for 2.5 but it's the similar of same for 2.3-2.4 I believe.

Here's the event

[touch event](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/TouchEvent.html)

and the handlers

[touch start](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/TouchStartHandler.html)

[touch end](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/TouchEndHandler.html)

[touch cancel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/TouchCancelHandler.html)

[touch move](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/TouchStartHandler.html)

[touch all](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HandlesAllTouchEvents.html) Note: For touch all there is a warning:

> WARNING, PLEASE READ: As this class is intended for developers who
>   wish to handle all mouse events in GWT, new mouse handler interfaces
>   will be added to it. Therefore, updates to GWT could cause breaking
>   API changes.

Comment: @user291701 what if you use rp.sinkEvents(Event.ONTOUCHSTART); and how do you know if it fires or not?

Comment: Blast, it works - I left the additional rp.sinkEvents() line for mouse events in, which came after the statement for touch events, so the touch events one was getting wiped out. Thanks!